# Prolog: generate queries out of DCG

Tags: prolog, call, dcg

I currently have a small Prolog database containing a few people and some predicates for relations. For example:

```
female(anna).
female(susan).

male(john).
male(timmy).

siblings(anna, susan).
siblings(anna, john).
siblings(susan, john).

sibling(X, Y) :- siblings(X, Y) ; siblings(Y, X).

%X is brother of Y
brother(X, Y) :- male(X), sibling(X, Y).
```

and I have a DCG which can determine valid questions like
"who is the brother of john", which also works well.

```
question --> ip, verb, article, noun, pronoun, name.
```

Now I want my program to make a call to my family-database out of noun and name like this:

```
noun(X, name).
```

Which in the example then should be

```
brother(X, anna).
```

and then return the answer as a natural-language answer like:

```
"the brother of anna is john"
```

Defining the grammer for the answer sentence is no problem either. The only thing I don't know is, how to make the call from my DCG to my database and to get the right values filled into it. I looked around for quite some time now - perhaps I don't know the right search terms - and couldnt find something related to this.

I hope you guys have some good ideas ! :)

Thank you.

Comment: Your definition of `sibling/2` does not terminate and thus `brother/2` does not terminate. Try `sibling(X,Y), false` to see it.

Comment: ah, yes thank you. changed it into: sibling(john, anna). siblings(X, Y) :- sibling(X, Y) ; sibling(Y, X). to get all and prohibit the endless recursion issues and other stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Invoking Prolog predicates from DCGs

### Regular way: Use `{}/1`

Use the nonterminal `{}//1` to call arbitrary Prolog goals from within DCGs.

For example:

```
verb --> [V], { verb(V) }.
```

This defines a nonterminal `verb//1`. This DCG describes a list consisting of the element `V` such that `verb(V)` holds, where `verb/1` is a normal Prolog predicate.

### In a sense even more regular: Use DCGs throughout!

Note that there is a second way to do this, which is in a sense even easier to understand: You can simply turn **everything** into DCG nonterminals!

For example, you could say:

```
female(anna)  --> [].
female(susan) --> [].
male(john)    --> [].
male(timmy)   --> [].
```

You could then simply use these nonterminals directly. You could define a `term_expansion/2` rule that does such a transformation *automatically*.

In your specific case, using `{}/1` is likely preferable, because you already have existing Prolog facts and. But there are definitely cases where using DCGs throughout is preferable.

**EDIT**: From your comment, I see your question is a bit more involved.

The question is rather about:

## Constructing Prolog goals from sentences

This is extremely straight-forward: Essentially, you only need to describe the **relation** between the Prolog goals you want and the corresponding sentences.

We do this by introducing a new argument to the DCG, and that argument will denote the Prolog goal that needs to be executed to answer the sentence. In your example, you want to relate the sentence "Who is the brother of susan?", to a call of the Prolog predicate `brother(X, susan)`. You already have a nonterminal `sentence//0` that describes such sentences. You only need to make explicit the goal that such sentences correspond to. For example:

```
sentence_goal(noun(X, name)) --> ip, v, a, noun, p, name.
```

This is only used to illustrate the principle; I'm not claiming that this is already the full solution. The point is simply to show that you can reason about Prolog goals in exactly the same way as about all other terms.

You can then invoke the actual goals in two phases:

1. first, relate the given sentence to the goal, using this new nonterminal `sentence_goal//1`
2. simply call the goal, using `call/1` or invoking it directly.

For example:

```
?- phrase(sentence_goal(Goal), Sentence), Goal.
```

In your case, all that remains is relating such sentences to the Prolog goals you want to invoke, such as `brother_of/2` etc.

None of this needs any side-effects (`write/1`)! Instead, concentrate on describing the **relations** between sentences and goals, and let the Prolog toplevel do the printing for you.

Comment: hi, thank you for your response. i didnt know term_expansion yet, thank you.  i changed my first rule to: sentence --> ip, v, a, noun, p, name, {call(noun, X, name), write(X)}. when then having a sentence like "who is the brother of susan", the call should be brother(X, susan) and X would unificate to john. at least i thought it would be like that does not work. can you clarify in more detail how i could do it? anyway your answer already helped me, thank you.

Comment: I have added an example that relates such sentences to goals, please adapt it as needed to your use case. I hope this illustrates the principle sufficiently. All in all, you now have a lot of flexibility: You can use `{}//1` to invoke arbitrary Prolog goals *within* DCGs, and you can even construct Prolog goals by simply describing them as terms, and then invoke them with meta-call or the `call/N` family of predicates. Focus on a clear declarative description of how these entities are related, and you will be able to use these relations in all directions.

Comment: thank you for your in depth answer mat! i fiddled around a little and i still think i missed a little bit. i have added such a line as you said:     sentence_goal(noun(X, name)) --> ip, v, a, noun, p, name.      and made a similar call, however prolog does not replace the noun and name with the actual values of the parsed sentence (brother and john). instead prolog takes them as atoms.

Comment: okay i fiddled with it a little more and came up with:  "question_goal(X) --> ip, verb, article, noun(Y), pronoun, name(Z), {call(Y, X, Z)}." which pretty much does, what i want - except then it wants to call X as a function again, which leads to: ?- phrase(question_goal(X), [who, is, the, sibling, of, john]), X.
ERROR: '<meta-call>'/1: Undefined procedure: anna/0

Comment: sorry for spamming, i realized my mistake now - everything was fine, i just needed to remove the ", X" from `?- phrase(question_goal(X), [who, is, the, sibling, of, john]) **, X**.`, then its not called and its fine :)

Comment: I think you still need to make up your mind: Do you want to describe Prolog *goals* (which you can call later), or describe the actual *answer* to the question? Your newest comments move towards the latter, and you now use `{}//1` *within* the DCG. Both approaches are fine and applicable in different situations, so I only have one comment on naming: In the latter case, your DCG nonterminal may, instead of the current `question_goal//1`, better be called  `sentence_answer//1`, `question_answer//1` or similar, since it relates a sentence/question to its answer, *not* to a Prolog goal.